# Inserting image to slide with empty placeholder (PowerPoint)

Tags: image, insert, powerpoint, placeholder

I want to insert a picture to my slide, but if there is an empty placeholder, the picture automatically gets inserted into this placeholder.

Is there a way to tell PowerPoint to avoid empty placeholders when inserting a picture?

Best regards
Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Is there a way to tell PowerPoint to avoid empty placeholders when inserting a picture?

No, but you can work around it by inserting your picture, getting a reference to the inserted shape, duplicating it, then deleting the original inserted shape.

The duplicate will be a picture, not a placeholder containing a picture.

That works most of the time; if your needs are more complex and/or you need to preserve the original placeholder, you'll need to add content to any empty placeholders, then insert your picture, then delete the added "bogus" content.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for your help. It's not ideal, but both suggestions are fine as a workaround. Best regards Jesper